# How to remove a row from a list in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/f4QP7gzTenvknyhuIdoA?p=preview)

I want to remove a row from a list. Initially the below code is there

```
var newArray = _.filter($scope.componentList, function(arrayItem) {
return rowId !== arrayItem.rowId;
});
$scope.componentList = newArray;
```

what this filter will do is if the return value is true then the filter contains that object otherwise it will remove that object.Now I just want to return the same for parents and childs also

Here `rowId` is the input for this function.
In the above `$scope.componentList = newArray;` line we will get what ever the `rowId` mached that object will be removed. And the remaining rowId's will be there in that list. it fine.

```
return rowId !== arrayItem.rowId;
```

In this line what ever returns true those are going to be there in newArray.

But now the format is changed. Now the format is like the bellow.

```
[
  {
    "revision": 0,  
    "componentName": "abc",
    "componentIdentification": "abc",
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "214",
    "rowId": "3",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "efg",
        "componentIdentification": "efg",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "215",
        "rowId": "3.1",
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "16",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  },
  {
    "revision": 0,
    "componentName": "hij",
    "componentIdentification": "hij",
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "206",
    "rowId": "1",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "klm",
        "componentIdentification": "klm",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "207",
        "rowId": "1.1",
        "items": [
          {
            "revision": 0,
            "componentName": "nop",
            "componentIdentification": "nop",
            "componentType": "2",
            "componentState": "1",
            "componentUrl": null,
            "componentId": "208",
            "rowId": "1.1.1",
            "items": [
              {
                "revision": 0,
                "componentName": "qrs",
                "componentIdentification": "qrs",
                "componentType": "2",
                "componentState": "1",
                "componentUrl": null,
                "componentId": "209",
                "rowId": "1.1.1.1",
                "items": null,
                "componentStateId": 0,
                "ctastatus": 0,
                "actionId": "26",
                "actionToPerform": "1"
              },
              {
                "revision": 0,
                "componentName": "tuv",
                "componentIdentification": "tuv",
                "componentType": "2",
                "componentState": "1",
                "componentUrl": null,
                "componentId": "210",
                "rowId": "1.1.1.2",
                "items": null,
                "componentStateId": 0,
                "ctastatus": 0,
                "actionId": "5",
                "actionToPerform": "1"
              }
            ],
            "componentStateId": 0,
            "ctastatus": 0,
            "actionId": "25",
            "actionToPerform": "1"
          }
        ],
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "1",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  },
  {
    "revision": 0,
    "componentName": "wxy",
    "componentIdentification": "wxy",  
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "211",
    "rowId": "2",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "zab",
        "componentIdentification": "zab",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "212",
        "rowId": "2.1", 
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "7",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      },
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "cde",
        "componentIdentification": "cde",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "213",
        "rowId": "2.2",
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "12",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  }
]
```

Now the parent and child relationship exist between one row and another with `items[]` array. So I try to write the code like below but it's not working.

**Method call:-**

```
var newArray = $scope.isRowIdExist($scope.componentList,rowId);
```

**method**

```
$scope.isRowIdExist = function(list,rowId) {

        var newArray = _.filter(list, function(arrayItem) {
            if(rowId != arrayItem.rowId){
                if (arrayItem.items && arrayItem.items.length > 0){
                    $scope.isRowIdExist(arrayItem.items,rowId); // method calling itself
                }
            }
            return rowId !== arrayItem.rowId;
        });

    }
```

Comment: a filter function calling recursively the function inside? what are you trying to do? Why you don't simply add a condition inside your filter function for checking also the items array contained in it?

Comment: @quirimmo yeah, Here The objects are there inside of another object i.e,,. parent and child relationship. Inorder to get the inner object I have return the recursive function

Comment: how checking `3.1` with `3` will work in the recursive call? I think your earlier implementation is fine enough for this case also, if the `rowId` itself is not there it will not remove the complete object itself

Comment: rowId maybe in child or parent? You want find row in parent or child and remove this row by id, right ?

Comment: @user3045654 yeah, you are right

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee If I use the earlier code then it will search  only for parents not to childs

Comment: Yes, and you will remove the complete parent, then why you bothered about childs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, target element with be replaced with "REMOVED", remove it from the splice function on production

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope){
    
    $scope.data = JSON.parse('[{"revision":0,"componentName":"abc","componentIdentification":"abc","componentType":"1","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"214","rowId":"3","items":[{"revision":0,"componentName":"efg","componentIdentification":"efg","componentType":"2","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"215","rowId":"3.1","items":null,"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"16","actionToPerform":"1"}],"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"37","actionToPerform":"1"},{"revision":0,"componentName":"hij","componentIdentification":"hij","componentType":"1","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"206","rowId":"1","items":[{"revision":0,"componentName":"klm","componentIdentification":"klm","componentType":"2","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"207","rowId":"1.1","items":[{"revision":0,"componentName":"nop","componentIdentification":"nop","componentType":"2","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"208","rowId":"1.1.1","items":[{"revision":0,"componentName":"qrs","componentIdentification":"qrs","componentType":"2","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"209","rowId":"1.1.1.1","items":null,"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"26","actionToPerform":"1"},{"revision":0,"componentName":"tuv","componentIdentification":"tuv","componentType":"2","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"210","rowId":"1.1.1.2","items":null,"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"5","actionToPerform":"1"}],"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"25","actionToPerform":"1"}],"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"1","actionToPerform":"1"}],"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"37","actionToPerform":"1"},{"revision":0,"componentName":"wxy","componentIdentification":"wxy","componentType":"1","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"211","rowId":"2","items":[{"revision":0,"componentName":"zab","componentIdentification":"zab","componentType":"2","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"212","rowId":"2.1","items":null,"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"7","actionToPerform":"1"},{"revision":0,"componentName":"cde","componentIdentification":"cde","componentType":"2","componentState":"1","componentUrl":null,"componentId":"213","rowId":"2.2","items":null,"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"12","actionToPerform":"1"}],"componentStateId":0,"ctastatus":0,"actionId":"37","actionToPerform":"1"}]');

    $scope.toDel = "1.1"
    $scope.removeElement = function (data, toDel, parent) {
      data.forEach(function(row, i) {
        if (row.rowId == toDel) {
          if (parent) {
            parent.items.splice(i, 1, "REMOVED")
          } else {
            data.splice(i, 1, "REMOVED")
          }
        } else if (row.items) {
          $scope.removeElement(row.items, toDel, row)
        }
      })
    }
    
    $scope.removeElement($scope.data, $scope.toDel, null);
  
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend avoiding filtering in this situation. This code works for removing a parent or a child:

```
function removeRow(items, rowId) {
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (rowId == item.rowId) {
            items.splice(i, 1);
        } else if (rowId.startsWith(item.rowId)) {
            removeRow(item.items, rowId);
        }
        if (item.items != null && item.items.length == 0) item.items = null;
    }
}
```

```js
var items = [
  {
    "revision": 0,
    "componentName": "abc",
    "componentIdentification": "abc",
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "214",
    "rowId": "3",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "efg",
        "componentIdentification": "efg",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "215",
        "rowId": "3.1",
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "16",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  },
  {
    "revision": 0,
    "componentName": "hij",
    "componentIdentification": "hij",
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "206",
    "rowId": "1",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "klm",
        "componentIdentification": "klm",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "207",
        "rowId": "1.1",
        "items": [
          {
            "revision": 0,
            "componentName": "nop",
            "componentIdentification": "nop",
            "componentType": "2",
            "componentState": "1",
            "componentUrl": null,
            "componentId": "208",
            "rowId": "1.1.1",
            "items": [
              {
                "revision": 0,
                "componentName": "qrs",
                "componentIdentification": "qrs",
                "componentType": "2",
                "componentState": "1",
                "componentUrl": null,
                "componentId": "209",
                "rowId": "1.1.1.1",
                "items": null,
                "componentStateId": 0,
                "ctastatus": 0,
                "actionId": "26",
                "actionToPerform": "1"
              },
              {
                "revision": 0,
                "componentName": "tuv",
                "componentIdentification": "tuv",
                "componentType": "2",
                "componentState": "1",
                "componentUrl": null,
                "componentId": "210",
                "rowId": "1.1.1.2",
                "items": null,
                "componentStateId": 0,
                "ctastatus": 0,
                "actionId": "5",
                "actionToPerform": "1"
              }
            ],
            "componentStateId": 0,
            "ctastatus": 0,
            "actionId": "25",
            "actionToPerform": "1"
          }
        ],
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "1",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  },
  {
    "revision": 0,
    "componentName": "wxy",
    "componentIdentification": "wxy",
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "211",
    "rowId": "2",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "zab",
        "componentIdentification": "zab",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "212",
        "rowId": "2.1",
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "7",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      },
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "cde",
        "componentIdentification": "cde",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "213",
        "rowId": "2.2",
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "12",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  }
];

/*
 Psuedocode:
 Do a fast recursive search for |item.rowId|=|rowId| and delete the one that matches
*/

function removeRow(items, rowId) {
 for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  var item = items[i];
  if (rowId == item.rowId) {
      items.splice(i, 1);
    } else if (rowId.startsWith(item.rowId)) {
   removeRow(item.items, rowId);
  }
    if (item.items != null && item.items.length == 0) item.items = null;
 }
}

removeRow(items, "1.1.1.1");
console.log(items);
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/f4QP7gzTenvknyhuIdoA?p=preview this is my plunker please check this

Comment: Oh I see my mistake, I only accounted for one level of children